# Bringing non-EU unmarried partner while on a Blue Card in Croatia

Tags: eu, blue-card, croatia

I am a non-EU citizen, not married, but in a longterm relationship with another non-EU person.

I am currently in process of recruited in Croatia with EU Blue Card

I have these following questions:

1. Is it possible to bring a non-married partner with you on a Blue Card? If yes, what are the ways to prove our relationship? According to my some findings 3 years of relationship needs to be proven. We are currently not living together.
2. If we get married after I get the Blue Card, can we apply for family reunification or is there a condition that we need to be married before I get Blue card?
3. Also is there another visa to get residency for my partner in Croatia?

Comment: Can you show your research that suggests you need to prove 3 years of living together?  Did that specifically apply to Croatia? The recognition of family relationships is determined by national law, I believe. I would not be surprised if Croatia only recognized marriages and registered civil partnerships, but I certainly do not know.  I suppose the answer to 2 is that you can marry subsequently. The answer to 3 is yes, your partner can get a visa just as any single person can, through work, education, etc.  Some countries have a visa for the "economically inactive"; I don't know about Croatia.

Comment: According to this document: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.hpc.hr/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Letak-za-web-engleski.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwink4SWj6L0AhWz7rsIHc2jBccQFnoECEIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1IGvrqiBZ7zPqyP2uBsCq- from foreign affairs office it declares even if you cannot prove relation with offical documents, somehow existence of your relation still assessed. How do they do this assesment? On 2nd page it says some statements of witnesses taken into consideration but is there any required proof?

Comment: That document applies to family reunion for refugees and people with similar "subsidiary protection."  It's possible that Croatia applies the same relationship criteria to family reunification for Blue Card holders, but it is likely to be different.  Unfortunately I don't have time to look myself at the moment.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?
My son is trying to navigate the same problem and can’t get a reply from the embassy. He has a job offer in Zagreb and want to take his partner with him Can you help??